# Hyphenation of particular languages in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, hyphenation

Is it possible to add new hyphenation rules to InDesign, and what languages does it have built-in hyphenation for?

Comment: I assume by “in what language does it hyphenate usually” you’re asking what languages InDesign has built-in hyphenation for, correct? There’s no “usually”—it always hyphenates according to the language specified in the paragraph style applied to the text in question. (Not sure what it does in the rare case that you get text with no paragraph style applied at all—probably just no hyphenation, I would guess.)

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Do you know if it's possible to modify it's hyphenation rules, or add a new language ?

Comment: I found Edit/Spelling/User Dictionary that allows you to add new hyphenated words. But what would you do if your language is not listed.

Comment: Which language are you talking about?

Comment: Albanian, it is no listed and I'm trying to find out if there is a way to add it, what would be the syntax etc ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible both to add new hyphenation rules to existing language dictionaries in InDesign and to add new language dictionaries.

#### Adding a language (Albanian)

The exact steps you have to take to add a dictionary for a new language vary according to your OS (operating system) and which version of InDesign you’re using. There is a [very clear and extensive guide on Adobe’s help pages](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/add_cs_dictionaries.html), which will help you.

There aren’t many Albanian Hunspell dictionaries available, but there is [one on GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/hunspell/tree/master/dicts/sq_AL), based on the older [Shkenca dictionaries](http://shkenca.org/k6i/). Note that these are not made by a corporative entity, but seemingly by a single person, so they may contain unspotted errors.

To install Albanian:

- download the `.aff` and `.dic` files from the GitHub page
- rename them to `sq_AL.aff` and `sq_AL.dic` respectively
- create a folder named `sq_AL` in the proper location (see step 4 on the Adobe help page) and put the two files in that folder
- open the file `Info.plist` in the proper location (see step 5 on the Adobe help page). Note: If you’re on a Mac, once you find `AdobeHunspellPlugin.bundle`, you have to right-click and select “Show package contents” to see the subfolder `Contents` where the plist file is located
- locate the lines in the file that say `<key>HyphenationService</key>`, `<key>SpellingService</key>` and `<key>UserDictionaryService</key>`. Immediately following each of those lines is a start tag `<array>`, followed by a list of `<string>xx_XX</string>` tags. Add a string tag `<string>sq_AL</string>` to that list. It doesn’t matter where in the list you put it.

The next time you restart InDesign, you should be able to choose Albanian as one of the languages you can set text in.

#### Adding words

As you mention in your comment, you can add your own words in addition to the ones already present in the Hunspell dictionary by using the *Edit* → *Spelling* → *User Dictionary* options.

The interface there is intuitive enough, but if you need more help, there is also an [Adobe help page on spell-checking and language dictionaries](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/spell-checking-language-dictionaries.html).

When you add a new word, you can click the *Hyphenate* button to suggest an automated hyphenation rule. This rule is based on the hyphenation rules set out in the Hunspell dictionary itself and will usually, but not always, be accurate. If you wish to tweak it to be absolutely how you want it, you can set the hyphenation options yourself.

Points 6 and 7 in the section [Add words to dictionaries](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/spell-checking-language-dictionaries.html#add_words_to_dictionaries) on the Adobe help page explains the syntax:

> - Tildes (~) indicate possible hyphenation points.
> - Type one tilde (~) to indicate the best possible hyphenation points, or the only acceptable hyphenation point, in the word.
> - Type two tildes (~~) to indicate your second choice.
> - Type three tildes (~~~) to indicate a poor but acceptable hyphenation point.
> - If you want the word never to be hyphenated, type a tilde before its first letter.

Comment: Followed your answer and added the new language successfully, but as you said it contains errors (shklluq is my test word and should never be hyphenated).  I would try to correct it, but I'm not sure how to edit to `sq_AL.aff` and `sq_AL.dic` .. (I created from scratch the hyphenation patterns in LaTeX).

Comment: Looking more closely at the preconfigured dictionaries included in InDesign, it seems that they all consist of _three_ dictionaries: an affix file, a spelling dictionary, and a hyphenation dictionary (`hyph_sq_AL.dic`). I can’t quite figure out how the automated hyphenation works when there is no hyphenation dictionary file, though.

Comment: That's huge because `hyph_en_Ca.dic` has the same rules as LaTeX, I already have the patterns for that.

Comment: @alfred I hope that means you have a way of figuring it out!

Comment: I might have some problems with it recognizing ë , ç and ' . Would it understand \lccode\'=\' ? Anyway I will know once I test it.

Comment: But yes, I should be able to add some proper hyphenation for albanian.

Comment: @alfred Just make it UTF-8, then you can type in those characters directly (at least ç and ë should work—not sure if ' needs to be escaped).

Comment: My patterns seem to work. It's surprising how easy this was. Thank you for your help Janus.

Comment: This does not answer the question since the question is about hyphenation and not spell-checking, does it?

Comment: @hkdalex My answer does not mention spellchecking in any way. Hyphenation and spellcheck both belong under the spelling-related set of services, and the Adobe help files deal with both on the same page,but they are not the same thing.